# Segmentation Fault on Pointer null check

Tags: c++

I'm getting a segmentation fault on the `if (currNode->right)` check. Can anyone spot the obvious mistake that I made?

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};

void Preorder(node *root) {

    std::stack<node*> currStack;

    currStack.push(root);

    while(currStack.top()) {
        node *currNode = currStack.top();
        currStack.pop();

        if (currNode->right) {
            currStack.push(currNode->right);
        }
        if (currNode->left) {
            currStack.push(currNode->left);
        }

        // Print to console
        printf("%d ", currNode->data);
    }
}
```

It might be related to my main function, so i'll add it below for reference:

```
int main() {

    node myNode;
    myNode.data = 3;

    node myNode1;
    myNode1.data = 4;
    node myNode2;
    myNode2.data = 5;
    node myNode3;
    myNode3.data = 6;
    node myNode4;
    myNode4.data = 7;

    myNode.left = &myNode1;
    myNode.right = &myNode2;
    myNode1.left = &myNode3;
    myNode1.right = &myNode4;

    Preorder(&myNode);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: What happened when you ran your program through a debugger? You still couldn't find where the error was?

Comment: A segmentation fault does not necessarily mean NULL pointer dereference. Use a debugger and see what's the value of `currNode`.

Comment: the debugger is showing that currNode has value in the beginning, but the value isn't printing out. Then when the currNode becomes NULL, it somehow manages to bypass the while loop condition and causes the segmentation fault.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It's standard, `std::stack` business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Problem: Change the loop condition to `while(!currStack.empty()) {}`

Answer (score 1):

This is due to uninitialized values of `left` and `right` pointers in `myNode2`, `myNode3`, and `myNode4`.

Define a constructor for `node` and you're good:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
    node() : data(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
};
```

Comment: seems to be crashing on the while loop check now. Sorry that I can't figure out the other error that still exists in the code.

Comment: Si Te Feng, you will need this as well as changing your while check to
    while(!currStack.empty())

Answer (score 0):

`currNode` seems to be invalid, e.g. NULL. You should check that case before using the pointer in the condition.

This might happen on your top stack node?

Comment: i'm assuming `while(currStack.top())` should take care of that??

Comment: You are getting the next pointer from your stack ``node *currNode = currStack.top();`` and assume, that the pointer is valid... A debugger would be a good solution as YSC suggested.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I find `while(currStack.top())` a pretty strange condition. `top()` returns a const reference, not a pointer (if you ever expected to get `NULL`). But if the referenced value is a pointer, and it is `NULL`, or if we get a reference to, say, int = 0, the loop ends.
Are you sure that's what you wanted? And if there are no elements in the stack, it probably results in an undefined behavior, but it definitely can't return `NULL`, if you expected that.

Comment: A reference to a `node*`, which can be NULL ;)

Comment: @YSC Right, and please read it again, I actually mentioned that, and said that the loop will end in this case. I just didn't think that he wanted to end it when he gets any NULL pointer.

Comment: @YSC And since he says above that his code is crashing on the while loop, he really wanted to check whether the stack is empty with while(currStack.top()), expecting to get a NULL in this case. Which he can't.